# Inline Translation is Not Enabling

Tags: inline-translations

There is only one store and one store view. Here is my path;

I disabled cache,

I enabled Inline Translation Feature from Conf>Developer>Inline Translation for Front End>Yes.

After that i opened Mozilla Firefox and typed the url of store and its just seem a normal store. So the problem is Magento is not enabling Inline Translation feature.

Comment: What is your question? What have you tried so far? Are you sure your theme is not the problem?

Comment: Delete var/cache folder and try.

Comment: frinds i have answer the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure, that you have nothing entered in

```
System > Configuration > developer > Developer Restriction > Allowed IPs
```

or if you have, that your ip is part of it.